# @QuerydslPredicate in spring test fails in standaloneSetup

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl, spring-rest

I am using @QuerydslPredicate as suggested in the spring document here.

[QueryDSL web support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe)
Everthing works fine when i run the web application. However for test cases when I am using

```
MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(classificationResource)
```

I am getting exception :-

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mysema.query.types.Predicate]: Specified class is an interface
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:101)
```

Things works fine when I load full context using .

```
 MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
```

My question is how to make this work in standaloneSetup ?

Answer (score 2):

In this case will help next resolver: *org.springframework.data.web.querydsl.QuerydslPredicateArgumentResolver*

Inject this resolver:

```
@Inject
private QuerydslPredicateArgumentResolver querydslPredicateArgumentResolver;
```

And then add resolver to context:

```
MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(classificationResource)
        .setCustomArgumentResolvers(querydslPredicateArgumentResolver)
        .build();
```